# Создание сложной композитной формы с помощью React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form, архитектура, spa

Передо мной встала задача реализовать SPA со сложной формой с использованием React-Redux. Поскольку я ни разу не фронтендер, я начал читать доки, сделал какой-никакой базовый шаблон для приложения и дошел до, собственно, реализации формы.

Схема работы приложения следующая: компонент верхнего уровня загружает большой json-объект с сервера в память. Большой - это значит объект с большим количеством полей. Условно, все поля разделены на секции.

Каждая секция может содержать как простые поля ввода, так и таблицы, переключатели и прочее, в том числе, поля только для чтения.

Сами поля и их стили предпочтительно генерировать самому, так как есть корпративный стиль и местные уже написанные контролы.

Также поля могут зависеть друг от друга, валидация полей может завистеть от значения других полей, зависимые поля могут быть из разных секций, и т.д. В общем, все, что может быть - возможно.

Для отображения и валидации полей возможны запросы на сервер (например, для данных для дропдаунов или для проверки валидности секции\поля).

Схематично это выглядит так:

---

```
| секция 1| набор полей 1 |
|--------:|--------------:|
| секция 2| набор полей 2 |
| секция 3| набор полей 3 |
| секция N| набор полей N |
|         |Кнопки действий|
```

---

По большому счету, вопроса возникает 2:

1) `Какой предпочтительный метод для управления состоянием формы и модели данных?`

С этим, в принципе, есть проблемы, но решаеммые. Насколько я понял, у меня 2 опции - хранить состояние в хранилище (сторе - я использую Redux), или хранить кусочки состояния в компонетнах и при каждой попытке закончить редактирование формы собирать это состояние и уже после обновлять хранилище.

Из того, что я понял в интернете и мауалов, делать ДЕЙСТВИЯ для обновления СОСТОЯНИЯ на каждый чих мне не стоит, так как контролов, доступных для редактирования много, а также в хранилище мне надо бы закидывать обновленную модель, которая уже прошла валидацию и сохранилась на сервере.

Таким образом, пока что у меня есть мысль каждую секцию делить на компонент, каждой секции-компоненту отдавать всю модель и коллбеки для валидации и обновления модели + у компонента должен быть метод, позволяющий компоненту выше по иерархии понять, проходит ли валидацию текущее состояние представления.

2) `Какой предпочтительный способ генерации всех этих контролов на форме, добавления туда бизнес правил и правил валидации?`

С этим ещё сложнее. Я смотрел [рекомендованный вариант](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/), [react-form](https://github.com/joepuzzo/informed), ещё раз [react-form](https://react-form.js.org/#/),
[react-redux-form](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form),
[не особо популярные варианты](https://github.com/Volicon/NestedLink) и много что ещё и так и не смог не то, чтобы выбрать, но и понять общепринятый подход к построению сложных каскадных форм. Каждая вещь на примере 2-3 полей кажется приемлемой, но когда предсталяю моё количество полей, то понимаю, что я утону в эвент хандлерах и магических функциях. `Отсюда вопрос - есть ли общепринятый, обкатанный способ реализации подобных нужной мне форм?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас уже форма разбита на секции, так и делайте. Тот же `redux-form` позволяет создавать несколько форм, которые вы можете подключить к одному компоненту. Сами поля подключаются через `Field`, где можно и валидацию [настроить](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/field.md/#-code-component-component-function-string-code-required-)

> Сами поля и их стили предпочтительно генерировать самому, так как есть корпративный стиль и местные уже написанные контролы.

В `redux-form` `Field` может принимать [функцию](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/field.md/#-code-component-component-function-string-code-required-) в качестве пропса, и отрисовывать ваш кастомный компонент. Там вы можете делать что хотите, не только со стилями, но и с валидацией, форматирование значения и так далее.

> Для отображения и валидации полей возможны запросы на сервер (например, для данных для дропдаунов или для проверки валидности секции\поля).

У `redux-form` есть настройка [`asyncValidate`](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-asyncvalidate-values-object-dispatch-function-props-object-blurredfield-string-gt-promise-lt-undefined-errors-object-gt-code-optional-), так можете отправлять запрос на сервер и получать статус валидации.

> но когда предсталяю моё количество полей, то понимаю, что я утону в эвент хандлерах и магических функциях

Если у вас сложная логика изменения поля, то вы в любом случае будите ее прописывать и ни какая библиотека вас не спасет, в остальном "магические функции", которые на деле просто кидают значения в стор (`value => dispatch({value})` ) сделают все за вас

Comment: Спасибо, перечитаю ещё раз. Возможно, я неверно понял сам как оно работает с первого раза.